# Basic Node JS configuration

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

I just installed Node JS on my ec2 instance (server) using the following site...http://iconof.com/blog/how-to-install-setup-node-js-on-amazon-aws-ec2-complete-guide/

I followed the instructions and I believe I downloaded it all properly, now I am trying to implement Node, but I do not think I am doing it right. I tried tutorialspoint.com but still cannot get it to work.

Basically I am using AJAX when a button is clicked, which in turn calls my node file...

```
$('#savePic').click(function(e)
{
$.ajax({
    url: "signupServer.js",
    type:'POST',
    data: new FormData($('#formpic')[0]),
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
}).done(function(){
```

and my node js file looks like this...

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    fs.writeFile("var/www/html/uploads/test", "Hey there!", function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

I am not using any of the `POST` data as referenced in my AJAX, I am simply using AJAX to call the code written in my `signupServer.js`.

The node js file above simply writes `"Hey there!"` to a file called test located at `/var/www/html/uploads/test`, but I cannot get it to work. I don't think anything is happening when the button `savePic` is clicked. Am I using node wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got most of the pieces, but went wrong in a couple places.

> 1. You need to run the node file as a server.
> 2. In your AJAX you call the the URL to hit the node server.

Using AWS(ec2) makes this a little more complicated. Your fist step should be to get a "hello world" node app running(there should be listen function in your Node server code) on AWS and successfuly pull up the app in your browsers. If you are new to AWS, this can take some time to figure out Once you get here, I think you will see how to change your code above.

Answer (score 0):

The file type in `fs.writeFile` isn't specified, it just says `var/www/html/uploads/test` but it's supposed to be saying `var/www/html/uploads/test.txt` (or any other file type of your choice)

If that still doesn't work, you'll need to figure out where the problem is.

- Run the server.
- load up the HTML file.
- Open the Network tab in google chrome dev tools. (Press Ctrl + Shift + J, then click Network)
- try clicking the button `savePic`.
- if you see a request go through, the problem is definitely server
  side.